# Jquery ajax call not working in anchor tag

Tags: asp.net, jquery, anchor

I have a link which downloads a file on click. I wrote a function on onclick event of that link tag to do some ajax operations when it is clicked.

But the function is not getting called when we click on that link.

However, if i debug the code or place a alert box in that js function, it just works fine. what will be the cause for this?

My code:

HTML:

```
<a href="DllLocation.dll" onclick=fntrackdownloads() ></a>
```

JS:

```
function fntrackdownloads() {
    $.get("default.aspx?RT=1", Responsetrackdownloads);    
}
```

Working code:

JS:

```
function fntrackdownloads() {
    $.get("default.aspx?RT=1", Responsetrackdownloads);    
    alert("something");
}
```

Any help will be appreciated.

> note: the anchor tag is generated dynamically from code behind and
>   written to dom. i am unaware of what dll location will come in href
>   attribute.

Comment: First priority for diagnosing AJAX issues - check the console for errors.

Comment: `$.get()` kicks off an asynchronous operation, so the normal link behaviour then occurs before the Ajax response.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan : no error is logged in console.

Comment: @nnnnnn: if thats the cause the ajax operation should work after the normal behaviour get over rite? but its not working. is there any other workaround to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$(document).("click", "a.putaclass", function(e) {
     //what to do on the click
     var $a=$(this);
     $.get(pathtoserver,function(d) {
         alert('data received:'+d);

          }) 

     return false;  //or e.preventDefault
    });
```

Comment: Note that `return false` won't do anything in the non-jQuery version unless the `onclick` is updated to return the result of the function. Also, I think the OP wants the normal click behaviour to occur in addition to the Ajax...

Comment: didn't understood question then; normal click behavior in addition to the ajax ?

Comment: all i want is that ajax call to work when clicked. either before download dialog or after downloading.

Comment: @Monie corleone remove onlick in html & bind your event as shown in edited answer in $(function($,undefined){}); or $(document).ready(function(){}); and add some class to your links

Answer (score 0):

I think you are missing the `"quotes"` here:

```
<a href="DllLocation.dll" onclick="fntrackdownloads()"></a>
//--------------------------------^------------------^
```

or more in jQuery way:

```
$('a[href="DllLocation.dll"]').click(function(){
  fntrackdownloads();
});
```

and

```
$('a[href="DllLocation.dll"]').click(fntrackdownloads);
);
```

Comment: Its not the problem with quotes. The anchor tag is generated dynamically in a previous ajax call and written to the Dom. thats y i didnt put the quotes there. when written to dom, the quotes will automatically appear.

Answer (score 0):

It's probably because the default anchor behaviour interrupts your AJAX response.

Try to put `return false` at the end of the function that's called on click and see what happens.